# Double-drop down weird behaviour

Tags: html, css, menu

Site: http://oppcess.test-lca-website.com/

I've been noticing an odd behaviour that is rather bizarre. I have a WordPress site and have created a horizontal sub-menu.  It works fine but the strangest thing happens.  If you move the mouse over the About button, the sub-menu drops but what gets strange is thatwhen you get to about 1/10th" of an inch away from the right-edge of the button, the dropdown suddenly changes to a vertical drop-down.  Even stranger, this ONLY happen when you move from left to right, I can't get it to do the same of I move from right to left.

This is the CSS I'm using for the sub-menu:

```
.block-type-navigation li:hover ul.sub-menu li {
    display: block !important; 
    float: left;
    width: 25% !important;
}

.block-type-navigation ul.sub-menu li a {
    min-width:100px;
}
```

Which does seem to work just fine.  I'm quite baffled by this seemingly '1 pixel' spot that shows the vertical menu.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `:hover` bit?

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks tons!